# C++ const class member function abs()

Tags: c++, templates, constants

#### Intro

I'm currently working on a implementation of a 'mathematical' vector, like in MATLAB, since I'd like to learn more about C++.
The Vector class has some constructors (including a copy constructor that is shown below), some operators (including a copy operator, shown below) and some methods (only relevant method shown):

```
template <class T = double>
  class Vector {
  public:
    Vector(Vector<T>& vec) : vector_(vec.vector_), size_(vec.size_) {}

    // ... some other constructors ...

    Vector<T>& operator=(const Vector<T>& other) {
      if (this != &other) {
        vector_ = other.vector_;
        size_ = other.size_;
      }
      return *this;
    }

    // ... some other operators, etc. ...

    Vector<T> abs() {
      Vector<T> result = *this;
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i != length(result); i++) {
        result.vector_[i] = fabs(result.vector_[i]);
      }
      return result;
    }

  private:
    std::vector<T> vector_;
    std::array<std::size_t, 2> size_{0, 0};
  };
```

FYI: `fabs()` comes from `#include <cmath>`.

Now I'm currently working on `abs()`, a element wise absolute value method.

#### Problem

Since `abs()` does NOT change the object itself, it could be made `const` like this:

```
Vector<T> abs() const { ... }
```

but, apparently this does not work and I get the following errors:

```
error: binding reference of type 'Vector<int>&' to 'const Vector<int>' discards qualifiers
       Vector<T> result = *this;

note:  initializing argument 1 of 'Vector<T>::Vector(Vector<T>&) [with T = int]'
       Vector(Vector<T>& vec) : vector_(vec.vector_), size_(vec.size_) {}
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question, and provide a [mcve] as required here please?

Comment: Copy constructor should take its argument by `const&`, exactly because of what you have here.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thanks for the quick response! That totally makes sense and solved my problem!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I tried to exclude everything unnecessary. Can you please tell me what isn't necessary in your eyes so I can formulate better questions in future?
I agree that everything template related wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your copy constructor cannot accept const reference. In this line

```
Vector<T> result = *this;
```

Copy constructor of `Vector<T>` is called. But when you mark your member function as const, `this` is also considered to be pointer to const. And when dereferencing you get const reference to `*this`, which you try to bind to non-const reference in your copy constructor. The solution is to make your copy constructor accept const reference

```
Vector(const Vector<T>& vec) : vector_(vec.vector_), size_(vec.size_) {}
```

As a general rule, you should accept arguments by const reference if you are not going to change them in the function. Copy constructor usually(in almost all cases) doesn't modify the object from which copying takes place.